# EF Code First not generating join tables for n:m relationships

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I've been using [this tutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) as a guide for code first n:m. I usually go with db first but for a school project I have to use code first...

My 2 classes are as follows:

```
public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        Stocks = new HashSet<Stock>();
        ServingUnits = new HashSet<Unit>();
        Orders = new HashSet<Order>();
    }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(128, MinimumLength = 1)]
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [StringLength(512, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int ExperationPeriod { get; set; }

    public byte[] Image { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    //foreign keys
    [Required]
    public int StockUnitId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CreatedById { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ProductStateId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ProductTypeId { get; set; }

    //navigation properties

    [ForeignKey("StockUnitId")]
    public virtual Unit StockUnit { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CreatedById")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductStateId")]
    public virtual ProductState ProductState { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductTypeId")]
    public virtual ProductType ProductType { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Stock> Stocks { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Unit> ServingUnits { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }

}
```

and the other:

```
public class Unit
{
    public Unit()
    {
        Orders = new HashSet<Order>();
        ProductsStock = new HashSet<Product>();
        ProductsServe = new HashSet<Product>();
    }
    public int UnitId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 1)]
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [StringLength(128, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public double BasisFactor { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    //foreign keys
    [Required]
    public string CreatedById { get; set; }

    //navigation properties    
    [ForeignKey("CreatedById")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> ProductsStock { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> ProductsServe { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

But the join table doesn't exist in my database. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: maybe its because you have two Collections of Product in the Unit Model. Why is that?

Comment: yes, you will need to some fluent code to define those relationships. https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-entity-framework/9781449317867/ch04s03.html

Comment: @SteveGreene - thanks for that. Can you add that in answer format please so I can accept? Thanks

Comment: Not really an answer, but if you get it working, post your own answer for others to see.